# ¿Como corro un archivo py dentro de otro py y el resultado del segundo lo redirecciono al primero?

Tags: python

Es un ejercicio de *sistemas operativos* en el que debo ejecutar este código dentro de otro programa:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from random import *
import sys


seed(int(sys.argv[1]))

for i in range(0,int(sys.argv[2])):
    a = randint(0,100)
print (a)
```

y a ese `print(a)` quiero guardarlo dentro de una variable `resultado`

Answer (score 1):

En este archivo *.py deberías crear una función que retorne a, y luego, desde el otro archivo hacer un import del archivo *.py donde está definida la función y llamar a esta última, asignando el valor retornado por la función a una nueva variable en este nuevo script.